# SSRS Display display table groups side by side

Tags: reporting-services, navision

Because I don't find a nice solution for my issue I hope to your expertise.

In a SSRS Report I have a dataset like this:

| Tracking_Print_Right_Side | Tracking_Title_No | Tracking_Serial_No | Tracking_Lot_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nein | 002 | SN00043 | CHARGE0015 |
| Nein | 002 | SN00044 | CHARGE0015 |
| Nein | 002 | SN00045 | CHARGE0015 |
| Ja | 002 | SN00050 | CHARGE0015 |
| Ja | 002 | SN00051 | CHARGE0016 |
| Ja | 002 | SN00052 | CHARGE0016 |
| Nein | 003 | XYZ01125 | CHARGE0017 |
| Nein | 003 | XYZ01126 | CHARGE0017 |
| Nein | 003 | XYZ01127 | CHARGE0017 |
| Nein | 003 | XYZ01128 | CHARGE0017 |
| Ja | 003 | XYZ01135 | CHARGE0017 |
| Ja | 003 | XYZ01136 | CHARGE0017 |
| Ja | 003 | XYZ01137 | CHARGE0017 |
| Ja | 003 | XYZ01138 | CHARGE0017 |

Expl.: Ja = True, Nein = False

As Result I will print it like this:

```
|     |            | False    | True     |
| 002 | CHARGE0015 | SN00043  | SN00050  |
|     |            | SN00044  |          |
|     |            | SN00045  |          |
|     | CHARGE0016 |          | SN00051  |
|     |            |          | SN00052  | 
| 003 | CHARGE0017 | XYZ01125 | XYZ01135 |
|     |            | XYZ01126 | XYZ01136 |
|     |            | XYZ01127 | XYZ01137 |
|     |            | XYZ01128 | XYZ01136 |
```

Row grouping on `Tracking_Title_No` and `Tracking_Lot_No` and a column grouping on `Tracking_Print_Right_Side`.

I can only create tables where the False and True Groups comes one after the other and not side by side.

How I should setup the tables?

The Tracking_Print_Right_Side is created by myself.

Mainly I will split the Charge group in the middle to save space in the report and use the whole width of the report.

Best regards

Bjoern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with a bit of work in SQL.

Here I have replicated your data and added a new column `RowN` which we can then use in the report to get the desired output.

Here's the full query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Tracking_Print_Right_Side sysname,Tracking_Title_No sysname, Tracking_Serial_No sysname, Tracking_Lot_No sysname)

INSERT INTO @t values 
('Nein' , '002', 'SN00043', 'CHARGE0015'),
('Nein' , '002', 'SN00044', 'CHARGE0015'),
('Nein' , '002', 'SN00045', 'CHARGE0015'),
('Ja' , '002', 'SN00050', 'CHARGE0015'),
('Ja' , '002', 'SN00051', 'CHARGE0016'),
('Ja' , '002', 'SN00052', 'CHARGE0016'),
('Nein' , '003', 'XYZ01125', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Nein' , '003', 'XYZ01126', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Nein' , '003', 'XYZ01127', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Nein' , '003', 'XYZ01128', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Ja' , '003', 'XYZ01135', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Ja' , '003', 'XYZ01136', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Ja' , '003', 'XYZ01137', 'CHARGE0017'),
('Ja' , '003', 'XYZ01138', 'CHARGE0017')

SELECT 
    Tracking_Title_No
    , Tracking_Lot_No
    , Tracking_Print_Right_Side
    , Tracking_Serial_No
    , RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tracking_Print_Right_Side, Tracking_Lot_No, Tracking_Title_No ORDER BY Tracking_Serial_No)
FROM @t
```

This gives us the following results...

[image]

If we look at serial numbers SN00050 and SN00043 they both have RowN = 1

We can now use this to group by in the report.

Here's the report design including the row groups. **NOTE** I left the RowN column in for clarity but you don't need it, as long as the rowgroup is present you can remove the column.

[image]

When we run the report we get the following...

[image]

Comment: Nice approach to insert another line number.
Thanks, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix instead of a table in SSRS